# Query select with next id order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with ID and NextID like this:

```
MainID  ||  NextID
1       ||  2
2       ||  3
3       ||  5
4       ||  6
5       ||  4
6       ||  ...
...     ||  ...
```

what I want to achieve is select data into like this

```
MainID  ||  NextID
1       ||  2
2       ||  3
3       ||  5
5       ||  4
4       ||  6
6       ||  ...
...     ||  ...
```

what i've tried is simple query like :

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' ORDER BY NextID
```

but of course it didn't meet my needs,
I have an idea to create a temp table and insert with loop but takes too much time to complete :

```
WHILE @NextID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 'table'(MainID, NextID)
    SELECT MainID, NextId
    FROM 'table' WHERE MainID=@NextID

END
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: edited, i'm really sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive cte will return rows in the order of nodes visited

```
with t as (
  select f.*, right('00000000'+cast(f.mainId as varchar(max)),9) path
  from yourtable f
  where MainID=1
  union all
  select f.*, path + '->' + right('00000000'+cast(f.mainId as varchar(max)),9)
  from t
  join yourtable f on t.NextID = f.MainID
)
select * 
from t
order by path
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdc660aaaa4ba3a37d142fae9141aefb)

`where MainId=1` is an arbitrary start. You may wish also start with
`where not exists  (select 1  from yourtable f2 where f2.Nextid = f.MainId)`

**Edit**

Added explicit `order by`

Comment: this is totally what i want,
it would be perfect if "where MainID=1" can be more flexible like get the lowest main id data
thanks sir !!

Comment: Probably `where not exists  (select 1  from yourtable f2 where f2.Nextid = f.MainId)`

Comment: No, this code returns rows in an *arbitrary* order because there is no `order by` in the outer query.  The code may *appear* to return rows in a particular order, but that is a coincidence and not guaranteed without an `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you may use right join with some ordering

```
select t2.*
  from some_table t1
 right join some_table t2
    on t1. main_id = t2.next_id
 order by case when t2.next_id is null then 9999999 else t2.main_id + t2.next_id end;
```

the 999999 in the "order by" part is to place last line (6, null) to the end of the output.

Good luck with adopting the query to your real data